# Carrera Virtuoso Rear Derailleur hanger bolt hole with HeliCoils?

Tags: frames, derailleur, derailleur-hanger

So, I broke a Shimano Sora rear derailleur last night... Ouch, there goes a load of cash...

What had happened was the hanger was bent slightly inwards, yet was functioning fine, so I rode it home. Came to a slight bump in the road whilst in first gear, and then the rear wheel spokes decided the derailleur looked tasty, caught the mech and bent it all the way up, over, in front of and then below the chain-stay. Long story short, it broke. Just in case you hadn't gathered. :P

I've repaired bikes for years, but I've never come up to this part; Can I use HeliCoils to place into the bolt holes for where the hanger itself is meant to meet? I cannot bring myself to part with this frame as it was my best friend's, and he had died after riding this bike in a small criterium near me, I brought it up to scratch, offered it to the family to help pay for funeral costs and they decided I should be the one entrusted to look after and care for it. I screwed up big time.

Theoretically, HeliCoils should ('should') work in this application; If it works holding brake calipers on cars, it should work for this. But, would there be any other way to fix the threads (which are warped and stretched, not even a thread chaser would work on it!) so I can still use the same bolt size? I don't want to have to bodge it together with a bigger bolt size in a larger, re-tapped hole. In fact, I'm not even sure THAT would work, either.

Could I put a big tack weld in where the hole is and then drill the weld out to tap a thread into? (After rubbing the paint back and all, though Aluminium is a pain to weld) I've never tried anything to do with frame/fork work directly, I'm used to fixing bikes, not frames, if you know what I mean by that.

Any help would be great, and I'm curious if HeliCoils would actually work. Cheers.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the damage?

Comment: I'll give it a go when I get back home tomorrow night, currently in a truck bed, lol. The threads are widened out and I'd just hammered it back flat again ready to commence dangerous man-stuff. :D

Comment: Depending on how its damaged, there may be easier ways to get around this (e.g. drilling the hole out a bit, and using something like Wheels MFG dropout savers). You also have options like the Problem Solvers universal derailleur hanger and things like that.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm dubious as to whether or not it'll work; Both threads have practically been pulled out. It looks like the Hulk has come along and pulled the bolts straight out rather than unscrewed them, lol.

Comment: Whatever you do, please take decent photos and post them in your own answer.

Comment: You've found out why spoke protectors are a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure that the holes were threaded to begin with?  Some hangers fit on both sides of the dropout, with screws running through, and the threading is in the "back" side of the hanger.

Comment: BTW, based on a quick Google, the Carrera Virtuoso eating its derailer appears to be a common occurrence.  If you look around (at other sites) you will find several threads on this topic.

Comment: Spoke protectors would not have helped in this case; it was the tension jockey wheel that was cannibalised. I saw a few on google, but wanted to find out about HeliCoils for a method of fixing, heehheh. I'll get some photos up tonight hopefully. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear, but I'm gathering that you've got a hanger that secures with two little screws, probably M3x0.5, that thread into the frame, and those frame threads are toast with some distortion/warping of the holes also present. If so it depends on how enlarged the holes are - the oversize tap that would come in the M3 helicoil kit has to have enough material to cut into to do its thing. Beyond that, there should be no issue.